# appcelerator hide actionBar from tabgroup

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I want to hide ActionBar from tabGroup in appcelerator titanium android.
When we create new project in appcelerator it by defaults has a tabbar and an actionbar on it. I want to remove that actionBar and only want to have tabs in my tab group I tried many codes one of them is as below

```
tabGroup.addEventListener("open", function() {
    var actionBar = tabGroup.getActivity().actionBar;
    if (actionBar) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
});
```

But this code sample also hides the tabs of my tabgroup. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Titanium mobile implements TabGroup and Tabs using ActionBar.Tab functionality  [Source code of Titanium TabGroup](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/tabgroup/TiUIActionBarTabGroup.java)

So if you hide the ActionBar, you will hide the Tabs as well :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you can set the tabGroup Title to empty, the Title bar will disappear automatically :

```
var tabGroup = Titanium.UI.createTabGroup({
     title:'',
});
```